# How to tell Apple that my Cocoa app is not ready for high resolution?

Tags: macos, cocoa, retina-display, magnification

Apple says that either **user** or **OS X** may decide to launch a Cocoa app in magnified mode instead of framework-scaled mode:

> All apps that are not Cocoa apps run in magnified mode. However, a Cocoa app can also run in magnified mode if:
>
> - The user sets the option to open the app in low resolution (see Figure 1-7).
> - The app is known to have significant issues when running in framework-scaled mode, so the system makes an exception and instead
>     runs the app in magnified mode.

([see link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Explained/Explained.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH4-SW10))

But how the **app developer** can launch it magnified? Or, how to force OS X to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the property `NSHighResolutionCapable` to **false** in your `Info.plist`.

In XCode, that property is called *High Resolution Capable*.

Comment: Thanks! Also, maybe helpful info: in old Xcode this property is _not_ called "High Resolution Capable", though it works. :)

Comment: In my tests setting the NSHighResolutionCapable property to false didn't have any effect at all. Asked about that at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426140/how-to-enable-use-low-resolution-on-retina-display-for-an-application-when-shi